# Sum from entries of 3 Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 5 mysql tables with the same layout:

```
name|||||||||points
-------------------
name1|10
name2|9
name3|11
```

...

I want to get the sum from all tables from a user so the result should be like this:

```
name|||||||||points
-------------------
name1|90
name2|59
name3|61
...
```

But my problem is, that some tables may not contain name1 for example, so a name can also be in 5 tables or in 1.

Comment: Why do you have multiple tables like this?  Depending on the rest of your DB (and potential future directions), making one table with some sort of differentiator column is completely valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Q.Name, SUM(Q.POINTS_COLUMN) Total
FROM
 (
  SELECT Name , POINTS_COLUMN  FROM TABLE_ONE
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Name , POINTS_COLUMN  FROM TABLE_TWO
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Name , POINTS_COLUMN  FROM TABLE_THREE
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Name , POINTS_COLUMN  FROM TABLE_FOUR
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT Name , POINTS_COLUMN  FROM TABLE_FIVE
  ) Q
GROUP BY Q.NAME
```